# Abstract Algebra Question about Operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we had a rule of an operation $*$ such as $x*y=x+2y-xy$, then would there be an identity $e$ for this operation? By the way, $*$ here is an operation on $\mathbb{R}$

This is what I did. To find an identity, we need to satisfy $x*e=x$,

1. $x*e=x$
2. $x+2e-xe=x$
3. $e(2-x)=0$
4. $e=0$, $x\neq 2$
5. Therefore, there is no identity for this rule of operation since for $x=2$, there's no identity.

Have I gotten this correct?

Comment: Why is $x = 2$ a problem? Your argument actually shows that $e = 0$ yields $x*e = x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Ash In addition to what others have said, $\;e=0\;$ is a **right identity** on the operation $\;*\;$.  To compute (for example) a left identity $\;f,\;$ you would have to consider the equation $\;f * y = y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = 2$ is not a problem; your argument shows that $e = 0$ implies $x*e = x$ for all $x$, and in fact it shows that it is the only possible value of $e$ that can work. However, you actually also need to show that $e*x = x$ for all $x$, and you can check that this cannot hold for $e = 0$. Hence, there is no identity.

Comment: If $x=2$, wouldn't I be dividing by $0$? Also, is it actually necessary to satisfy $e*x=x$ since in this case, $x*y$ is not commutative? Let me know.

Comment: Actually you are right we need to check the left identity. But I'm still confused about the whole $x=2$ bit.

Comment: Your computation shows that **if** $x*e=e$ and $x\neq2$ **then** $e=0$, and for this to work you really did need $x\neq2$. But to show that $0$ is a right identity element, you need the converse: **If** $e=0$ **then** $x*e=e$. Your computation would show that if you read it in reverse, and that doesn't require $x\neq2$ because you'd be multiplying by $2-x$, not dividing.